# ADAL Authentication Error Multi-Tenant

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, office365

I taken the sample code from the GIT for multi-tenant.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant

In https://manage.windowsazure.com/ i enabled MULTI-TENANT to YES. But when ever i tried to login with different organization i am getting error as follows.

User account 'vtest@someconsuting.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' does not exist in tenant 'My Test App ' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

How can i resolve this??

Comment: What kind of url do you use to login ?

Comment: you mean for api request or my web app url?

Comment: yes, but i see Jeffrey give you the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to my problem. From this URL https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/blob/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/AspNetMvc-MultiTenant/

I copied the following files to my project

TokenCacheDBContext.cs

SqlDBTokenCache.cs

ServiceConstants.cs

App_Start/Startup.auth.cs

I ran the project and got one error for Office365AssertedFailedException. For that i created one more class file like

Office365AssertedFailedException.cs

I rebuild the code again and got success. Now i am able to login with multi-tenants.

Comment: It's glad to know that you can use my sample code to fix this issue, I've rewritten the TokenCache in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your authority url is "https://login.windows.net/common".

If your authority url is "https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}", you will get the error as following:
[image]

To fix this issue, in the Startup.Auth.cs, config the authority url as "https://login.windows.net/common".

```
    var authority = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ServiceConstants.AzureADEndPoint, "common");

    var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
        ClientId = OAuthSettings.ClientId,
        Authority = authority,
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        }
    };
```

[sample Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/blob/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/AspNetMvc-MultiTenant/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)

Comment: I am getting a new error on login page as IOException: Unable to get document from: https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I tried to resolve that error but getting another error like this...."Application with identifier xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx was not found in the directory enukesoftware.onmicrosoft.com"

Comment: Getting IO exception again...IOException: Unable to get document from: api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/common/.well-known/...

Comment: ServiceConstants.AzureADEndPoint = "https://login.windows.net";, in your case, you used "https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/";

Comment: Now it is redirecting to office 365 but getting another error like .. An exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: authority_not_in_valid_list: 'authority' is not in the list of valid addresses

Comment: I resolved authority issue as well , but still getting another error like An exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll

Comment: I'm not sure why this error occurred based on the current information. But if the answer could resolve the multi-tenant authentication error, I suggest you closing this one and starting a dedicated question with more detail information. For example, code to reproduce this issue. It will also help others who have the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just replaced

```
    string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.net/common/";
```

with

```
    string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common";
```